# [TypeScript]: Indexing type by two generics enums

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to get the return type of a function from a type by an index, where the index is a generic type variable.

Code:

```js
enum PROTOCOL { P1 = 0, P2 = 1 };
enum PROTOCOL_P1_SPACE { S11 = 0, S12 = 1 };
enum PROTOCOL_P2_SPACE { S21 = 0, S22 = 1 };

type OBJECT = {
    [PROTOCOL.P1]: {
        [PROTOCOL_P1_SPACE.S11]: { a: string },
        [PROTOCOL_P1_SPACE.S12]: { b: Array<number> },
    },
    [PROTOCOL.P2]: {
        [PROTOCOL_P2_SPACE.S21]: { c: number },
        [PROTOCOL_P2_SPACE.S22]: { d: Buffer },
    },
};

function getObject<
    TProtocol extends PROTOCOL,
    TSpace extends PROTOCOL_P1_SPACE | PROTOCOL_P2_SPACE
>(query: string): OBJECT[TProtocol][TSpace] { return call('getObject', query); };
```

TypeScript throws the error `Type 'TSpace' cannot be used to index type 'OBJECT[TProtocol]'.`
How to fix it?

---

---

P.S. VSCode can understand what i want:

```js
const p1s1 = getObject<PROTOCOL.P1, PROTOCOL_P1_SPACE.S11>('p1s1');
const p2s1 = getObject<PROTOCOL.P2, PROTOCOL_P2_SPACE.S21>('p2s2');
```

It understand, that `p1s1` is `{ a: string }` and `p2s1` is `{ c: number }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the type of `TSpace` be dependent on the type of `TProtocol`. One way to achieve this would be like this:

```
function getObject<
    TProtocol extends PROTOCOL,
    TSpace extends keyof OBJECT[TProtocol]
>(query: string): OBJECT[TProtocol][TSpace]
```